# A SQL query to count how many attributes a record has in common with another record?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query to take the count of columns with equal value in my schema for each row by comparison to a single record.
Example:

```
record1: 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
record2: 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
record3: 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

`record1` has 2 attributes in common with `record2`, go through the entire table and order by number of attributes each record has in common with `record1`

Is there a way to write a SQL statement that will do this?  I have only found ways to compare each row and specify which attributes must be of equal value.

Comment: Do you count null values?

Comment: No, I'd prefer to exclude null values from the overall count.  I think the query from Gordon could be easily modified to account for this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when t.col1 = t1.col1 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t.col2 = t1.col2 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t.col3 = t1.col3 then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
       ) as num_in_common
from t cross join
     t t1
where t1.id = 1;  -- or however you define "record1"
order by num_in_common desc;
```

Comment: Are t and t1 the same table just referenced twice?  (Like "from table_1 t, table_1 t1").  Thanks!

Comment: @T1992 . . . Yes, `t` and `t1` are the same table referenced twice in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice routine you can use in SQL Server that will do this if you'd like.  Replace #temp with your table name:

```
declare @holding table (id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, num_in_common int)
declare @iterator int = 1
declare @row1col1 int, @row1col2 int, @row1col3 int, @row1col4 int ,@row1col5 int
while @iterator<=(select max(id) from #temp)
begin
if @iterator=1 
select @row1col1=col1, @row1col2=col2, @row1col3=col3, @row1col4=col4 ,@row1col5=col5
from #temp where id=@iterator
else
insert @holding
select *, case when col1-@row1col1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end +
          case when col2-@row1col2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end +
          case when col3-@row1col3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end +
          case when col4-@row1col4 = 0 then 1 else 0 end +
          case when col5-@row1col5 = 0 then 1 else 0 end 
from #temp where id=@iterator
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end
select * from @holding
```